# Async cleanup on observable sequence termination

Tags: rx-java

I need to execute an asynchronous method (e.g. a cleanup job) on an observable completion/failure. Also if the cleanup method fails the observable chain should also fail.

Is there a standard way of doing this?

Suppose I have a sequence Observable source and asyncCleanup() method that returns an observable cleanup result.

The side effect methods such as doOnCompleted/doOnTerminate/doOnUnsubscribe do not seem to be suitable:

```
source.doOnUnsubscribe(()->asyncCleanup().subscribe());
```

The observable chain will succeed even if asyncCleanup() fails.
So asyncCleanup() should be a part of the same chain.

The best I came up with is the following:

```
source.onErrorResumeNext(err->asyncCleanup()
         .flatMap(cleanupResult->Observable.error(err)))
      .concatWith(asyncCleanup()
         .flatMap(cleanupResult->Observable.empty()));
```

In case of failure, onErrorResumeNext will call asyncCleanup() and will map back to to the original error.
In case of success, we can concatenate with asyncCleanup() mapped to an empty sequence.
Unfortunately, it is not going to work if there is a take() or similar limiting operator downstream, which may cause the concatenated observable not even subscribe.

**UPDATE 2017-08-01**:
The question is specifically about sequence observables. For a single-item observable source the solution is quite simple:

```
singleItemSource
    .onErrorResumeNext(err->asyncCleanup()
        .flatMap(cleanupResult->Observable.error(err)))
    .flatMap(single->asyncCleanup()
        .map(cleanupResult->single));
```

Comment: What is the side effects of doOnCompleted/doOnTerminate/doOnUnsubscribe

Comment: I meant "side effect methods". This is how these methods are called by convention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea you propose breaks the `Observable` contract, because:

> ***Rx Design Guidelines***, 6.8 - Unsubscription should not throw

The only thing that comes to my mind to solve your problem is to turn `asyncCleanup()` to the same type of the preceding sequence and in case of success return for example Observable.empty(), the you can use the `concat` operator.

```
public Observable<Long> asyncCleanup() {
...
    return Observable.empty();
}

//Concat asyncCleanup() to be executed after the sequence
Observable.rangeLong(1, 10)
            .concatWith(asyncCleanup())
            .subscribe(System.out::println, System.out::println);
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: i am not proposing anything any idea, just asking a question :) also if you read my question fully i posted exactly this solution, it is not going to work if you put take(5) down the chain.

Comment: Yes it works, just put the take(5) before  the concat.

Comment: sorry i specifically meant down the chain

Comment: The main idea of this solution is to put the concat operator down the chain, after the whole processing of the first observable is done.

Comment: ok imagine down the chain seats a client that is free to limit items issues by my observable source using take or first or any limiting operators. that client has no business understanding that he has to clean up anything.

Comment: Then try ```Observable.using``` instead this approach, using operator is another way to call cleanup. The drawback is you shouldn't throw while disposing...

Comment: I marking this as a correct answer: Simply not possible.

Comment: For more details, read akarnokd's comment about *umap* situation.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [`flatMap`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/1.x/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#flatMap(rx.functions.Func1,%20rx.functions.Func1,%20rx.functions.Func0)) overload that let's you map the `onXXX` events of the upstream into `Observable`s:

```
Observable.range(1, 10)
    .flatMap(Observable::just, e -> asyncCleanup(), () -> asyncCleanup())
    .subscribe(...);
```

Comment: not working if you put take(5) down the chain!  onCompleted is simply never issued by the source so asyncCleanup() never subscribed.

Comment: Put it in front of the flatMap. Otherwise it is a contradiction since you tell the stream to stop sending you events yet want to receive the outcome of the asyncCleanup.

Comment: take() operator is way down the chain used by the client which is not aware of any cleanup that has to be done. All I need is cleanup to happen before onCompleted is sent to this client.

Comment: The problem is that the `onComplete` you want to respond to happens way down the chain after any operator or logic you want to apply at the top. This is a so-called **umap** situation where you don't offer an `Observable` to the client but ask it to given a flow, return a flow in response, and thus you are in control of the input and take the output of the client's flow. This prohibits `subscribe()`.

Answer (score 0):

The other solution I commented avobe is the factory method `Observable.using`. Here is a simple example of how it works:

```
Observable<Long> range = Observable.rangeLong(1, 10);

Observable.using(() -> range, //The resource provider
            observable -> observable, //The resource
            observable -> asyncCleanup() //The resource disposer
                     .subscribe(System.out::println, System.out::println))
    .subscribe(System.out::println, System.out::println);
```

The drawback here is that you should handle `asyncCleanup()` success and errors, without propagating or throwing. With this approach you should think about moving away from Observables in the case of `asyncCleanup()` method.

Comment: This solution does not provide any improvements compared to the one I mentioned in the question with doOnUnsubscribe side effect method. If there is no really solution to this problem within RxJava, I would prefer it is written down as a separate answer to which I will assign the bounty, in case there will be no acceptable answers.

Comment: @yurgis, you can always implement your own operators, transformers, observables or contribute to RxJava project... Regards

Comment: yeah, I guess what is missing is a Using signature with async disposal of a resource